# How to convert UTC Datetime to Salesforce DateTime Object

Tags: apex, datetime

I have the following date

2013-01-30T07:38:44.268Z

and I need to convert it to a datetime object. can you explain how?

Answer (score 1):

you can put the date into a sting and do the following

```
String dateStr = '2013-01-30t07:38:44.268z';
dateTime xx = dateTime.valueOf(dateStr .replace('t',' '));
```